# Add existing Docker container to Kubernetes cluster in Rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, rancher

I have setup RancherOS on Google Cloud and have configured four instances (Rancher server + three agent nodes). On one of the agent nodes, i have GitLab CE 9.3.9 running. *I later configured Rancher agent on it*. Now when i check the Kubernetes dashboard's `Hosts` section, i see that it recognizes the GitLab container and mentions it under `Standalone Containers` section. I would like to make it part of the Kubernetes cluster. I see there is a `clone` option for GitLab container. Is that the one which i have to use to make it part of the cluster? If not, is there a way to import it into Kubernetes?

[image]

While setting up GitLab, i just ran the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker run --detach \
     --hostname gitlab.example.com \
     --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 \
     --name gitlab \
     --restart always \
     --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
     --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
     --volume /mnt/data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
     gitlab/gitlab-ce:9.4.5-ce.0
```

Comment: If this is a production Gitlab your are using, then i would suggest, don't touch it. There is not much value moving this to Kubernetes as you want to run it on a single and not to scale it. So best to leave it as it as and not add complexity to the setup. Because else you need to build all the kubernetes yaml and create hostmount and restrict it to execute on that specific node only

Comment: This is a test setup but i am wondering how will read/writes happen if a cluster is configured. Each container will have its own db (PostgreSQL), correct? Instead, what's expected is to have read/writes from/to a common db. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Each container won't have PostgreSQL. Also I would suggest you to do complete deployment of gitlab from scratch than doing a snowflake deployment like this, which cannot be reproduced. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/ for more info